# Windows 7: fullscreen apps get put to last place in the alt-tab order

Tags: windows-7, alt-tab

I love using alt-tab between two windows, however it starts working in an unexpected way when one of them is in fullscreen mode. I play a game, alt-tab to  a browser, but then the next alt-tab brings up not the game, but some other application, as the game selection is pushed to the very last place in the alt-tab queue. I tried searching, but all I found was topics about being slow to switch, not the order. How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and you'll always switch to the 'last' window, which in your case is the one you want.

Otherwise you can apparently 'change' the alt tab switcher to the old one, which *may* give you the functionality you want, by following the instructions on this [site](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/get-more-from-windows-7-alttab-app-switching-tricks-you-didnt-know-about/). Basically you want to add a registry key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTabSettings` with a dword value of 1. To revert it, just delete the key again.